# Seaborn box plot broken after update to 0.6.0

Tags: matplotlib, boxplot, seaborn, violin-plot

I have recently updated my seaborn from 0.5.1 to the new 0.6.0 version. I had been using seaborn to make box plots and violinplots in python notebookand now I can't seem to make my code work anymore. Matplotlib `plt.boxplot` still works with my data. Particularly, the problem seems to happen when I have a group of lists or arrays in which the subsets are different in size.

e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
x = np.array([1,3,4]), ([1,2])
plt.boxplot(x) #this works



 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import seaborn as sns
 x = np.array([1,3,4]), ([1,2])
 sns.boxplot(x) #doesn't work
```

This is the error I get when I try the seaborn box plot

> ValueError: List of boxplot statistics and  `positions` values must
>   have same the length

In the new seaborn tutorial, it says `sns.boxplot` should take everything that `plt.boxplot` does. Has anyone had the same problem with the update? Is there a way of making this work? If not, is there a way of installing both the 0.6.0 version and the 0.5.1 version and calling a specific version in certain notebooks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in the [release notes](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/whatsnew.html#changes-and-updates-to-categorical-plots) there have been some changes to the API for categorical plots.

In your case, you just need to explicitly pass your list (tuple, technically) of arrays to the `data` parameter:

```
sns.boxplot(data=x)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. Is there a way of adding x labels to the values? I haven't been able to do that either.

Comment: If you use a DataFrame, the column names will be used as labels. See numerous examples here: http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html#seaborn.boxplot

Comment: Thanks. For the lists, I just figured I can use:
x = np.array([1,3,4]), ([1,2])
box=sns.boxplot(data=x)
box.set_xticklabels(['a','b'])